# VSIX - Use "Managed Compatibility Mode" debug engine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, vsix

Does somebody know how we can use the "Managed Compatibility Mode" debugger, to attach to a process from inside a VSIX package code with VS2015?
We currently use the following code, to find the "Managed 4.0" engine, but it seems that the "Managed Compatibility Mode" engine cannot be found.

```
foreach (EnvDTE80.Transport tr in Debugger.Transports)
    foreach (EnvDTE80.Engine eng in tr.Engines)
    {
        if (VisualStudioDebugEngines.Managed40.Equals(new Guid(eng.ID)))
        {
            transport = tr;
            engine = eng;
        }
    }

process.Attach2(engine);
```

In other words: how to do this in code:

[image: Managed Compatibility Mode]

Comment: That option enables the "old" debugging engine.  Use Regedit.exe to review the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\AD7Metrics\Engine registry key.  There are several candidate Guids listed there, I don't know which is the right one, only which one is the wrong one.

Comment: Via the following site, I found out that the GUID is "{351668CC-8477-4fbf-BFE3-5F1006E4DB1F}" : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx. How do I find the correct engine to pass to the Attach2() method?

Comment: Can you give a little background on your scenario? Is this for a regular managed project or a custom project type? Have you tried COMPlusLegacyEngine_guid?